# Testing the tooltip / customValidity message with Codeception/Selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium, codeception

On my Codeception scenario I would like to check when I submit a form with some user error ( e.g confirm a wrong email), the browser show the tooltip with my custom message.

**HTML**

```
<form ... >
    <label>Email *</label>
    <p>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email placeholder="Please insert your email" required="1" autocomplete="off" />
    <input type="email" name="email_r" id="email_r" placeholder="Please confirm your email" required="1" autocomplete="off" />
    </p>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
MyPlugin.checkMatch = function (idInputReferring, idInputRepeat){
   var inputReferring = document.getElementById( idInputReferring );
   var inputRepeat = document.getElementById( idInputRepeat );
   if (inputReferring.value !== inputRepeat.value) {
        inputRepeat.setCustomValidity( "It is must match with the previous input" );
        inputRepeat.checkValidity();
        setTimeout(function() {
        inputRepeat.reportValidity();
        }, 1);

    } else {
        inputRepeat.setCustomValidity('');
        inputRepeat.checkValidity();
    }
};
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the tooltip error message from `validationMessage` attribute from the input element.

Answer (score 0):

One solution ( but it does not prove that the browser show the tooltip ) :

```
$I->executeJS('return document.getElementById("email_r").validity.invalid;');
$I->executeJS('return jQuery("#email_r").validationMessage === "It is must match with the previous input"');
```